# Laravel manage translations with one table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I came from CakePhp world and a newbie to Laravel. In cakephp, it was possible to translate all models with one table. 
The table scheme was something like this:

```
id,language,model,foreign_key,field,content
```

Every translations would be in one table and you just have to set in your model which fields you want to translate. I don't find that kind of structure in laravel. It would be too much code/tables if I have to make a extra table for every new model that I want to translate.

So, does anyone have any idea how this could be achieved in laravel? I see there aren't any events while getting data.

Comment: Are you looking to have all translations (including the primary language) in a `translations` table? Or have a table for each model that stores the primary language values and any additional translations to be in that `translations` table (such as having a `Product` model that has the corresponding `products` table with, let's say, `name` and `description` columns that store the values in English, and any other language translations for that model to be stored in the `translations` table with the structure you described)?

Comment: @Bogdan I want one table to have all translation (including the primary language)

Comment: There a few packages that can be installed to handle Eloquent model translations, but they all seem to go about solving this by having a secondary table for each model that stores translations, which when you have many models that need translations can result in a lot of extra tables. That is probably because it can take some doing to implement this by having a global `translations` table like you described.

Comment: To solve this requires making some changes to how Eloquent models work as far as fetching and storing model information goes (having a `Translatable` trait in which you handle the logic might be a good approach). I would also suggest making use of [Polymorphic Relations](http://bit.ly/1EabVmj) which allow you to map the model to translation values easily.

Comment: You can have a look to see how [this package](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable/blob/master/src/Translatable/Translatable.php) handles the fetching and storing of different translations and adapt it to work with a single translations table.

Comment: @Bogdan yess I was lookig at that just now. I really appriciate your help. Ill try making a trait, maybe can you help ?

Comment: I'll have a look when I have a little more time (today I won't be able to anymore), and get back to you with some more specific suggestions, and perhaps post an answer with a working concept for this. In the mean time you can try having a go at it and if you hit some roadblock, you can edit the question and post the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: @Bogdan ya sure.. thank you :)

Comment: @Bogdan, is it possible to inspect the data which is returned from get() ?

Comment: Short of using a debugger, you could use `dump($var);` and it will output a nicely formatted var dump.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/LaravelArab/tarjama

I also migrated from cakephp and this was the package that came closest to what I wanted.
Unfortunately, today it is not compatible with Laravel 7.